# How to remove folder name from subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have Domain name like :

```
http://test.domain.com/godadmin/login
```

i want to hide **godadmin** from URL

Like : `http://test.domain.com/login`

How ?

Thanks.

Comment: This depends on the platform, framework or how the code is written. Can you share the details of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but a general answer is probably the following rule. It will internally rewrite all requests to `/...` on the host it is defined inside to `/godadmin/...`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /godadmin/$1 [END]
```

If you encounter an "internal server error" (http status 500), then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will find hints to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. Either upgrade your http server or use the older `[L]` flag in that case, it will probably work the same in this scenario...

That rule should work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file). If you decide to use such a dynamic file then the interpretation of such files needs to be enabled inside the http servers host configuration and you need to place the file in the host's DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).